# How to remove empty value from object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

How to remove empty value from object  in angularjs-

Here is my JavaScript code

```
$scope.addRole = function() { 
                            var tempDept = "";
                            angular
                                    .forEach(
                                            $scope.departments,
                                            function(value, key) {
                                                if (value.name == currentDepartment) { console.log(value.name);
                                                    tempDept = currentDepartment;
                                                    if (value.roles != "") value.roles
                                                    //value.roles
                                                            .push({
                                                                name : $scope.role.name,
                                                                //responsibilities : $scope.role.responsibilities
                                                            });
                                                }
                                            });
                            $scope.save(tempDept);
                            $scope.role = {
                                name : "",
                                responsibilities : []
                            };

                                $scope.role.responsibilities.push({name : ""});
                                $scope.role.responsibilities.push({name : ""});
                                $scope.role.responsibilities.push({name : ""});
                                currentDepartment = "";
                                console.log($scope.role.responsibilities.name);
                                $scope.role.responsibilities.splice(index, 1);


                            //$scope.save();
                        }
```

i want to remove empty value of object and how can do it? give me some suggestions..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS remove empty value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067327/angularjs-remove-empty-value)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean remove a property of an object ?

like -

```
var a = {
    b : 1 
};

delete a.b; // a.b === undefined now
```

Comment: i want to remove empty value of responsibilities

Comment: remove from the array? a specific one ? or all the ones that are null\undefined\empty?

Comment: all the ones that are null\undefined\empty

Comment: $scope.role.responsibilities.filter(function(res){ return res != null && res != undefiend  && res != ""; });

Comment: Thanks i try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the property of the object using the following:

```
delete object.property
```

Here in this case, you can simply delete the properties as:

```
delete $scope.role.responsibilities.name;
```

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `angular custom filter` for it.

I have created a `plunker` code, which may help you.
https://plnkr.co/edit/8YWxlr?p=preview